# Questions about : Featured Enum Instead of Switch ... using lambda, enum, closures function

Tags: python, enums, switch-statement, closures

Featured Enum Instead of Switch ... by using lambda, enum, closures function

Sorry, I thougth I understood it a little bit after watching a tutorial about :

Programming Terms: Closures - How to Use Them and Why They Are Useful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swU3c34d2NQ

I have some issues, questions to try to understand the code better over here.

1. in pycharm :

   ```
   switcher = {                # info : dictionary
               ...
               11: eleven,
               12: twelve      # info : enum def twelve() -> str
    }
   ```

   if I hover with the mouse over '`switcher`' --> info : `dictionary`

   if I hover with the mouse over an 'element' of switcher -

   ex. twelve of
               `12: twelve` --> info : `enum   def twelve() -> str`

   #### How is the connection, relation made to the function over here ?

   ```
   12: twelve --> info : enum   def twelve() -> str
   ```

   #### Why does it **NOT** to be with () - parenthèse?

   Just like calling a function - by `functionname()` 
   (in the dictionary)

   like this?

   ```
   switcher = {  
               ...
               11: eleven(),
               12: twelve()
    }
   ```
2. in '`switcher.get(argument, lambda: (" ...` ',

   - **IF** true  : return value : argument [if excist] otherwise

     **ELSE**     : [*NONE*] default value
   - what is the goal or meaning of '`lambda`' over here ?

     If I replace it by a string, it throws an error.

     `func = switcher.get(argument, 'Invalid month [1-12]') 
        # TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

     How I experience it, that is just for creating a function.
     It doesn't work without.

     #### So why does it has to be a function (lambda)?

     (if I understand that part correct)

     https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get
3. when I replace in the function '*twelve*'

   `def twelve():
      return ("December")`

   into

   `return ("December  : {input}".format(input=argument))`

   To show the argument : '*argument*' this results in a

   `NameError: name 'argument' is not defined`

   #### How is it possible to give an *argument* to the function ?

   (I used just the same variable, but it may be any other kind of variable, instance, list, dictionary, set, string ...)

---

the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def one():
   return "January"


def two():
   return "February"


def three():
   return "March"


def four():
   return "April"


def five():
   return "May"


def six():
   return "June"


def seven():
   return "July"


def eight():
   return "August"


def nine():
   return "September"


def ten():
   return "October"


def eleven():
   return "November"


def twelve():
# def twelve(argument):
   print(' --- in function :  twelve')
#   print(' --- in function :  twelve : {input}'.format(input=argument))    # results in a NameError: name 'argument' is not defined
   return ("December")
#   return ("December  : {input}".format(input=argument))                   # results in a NameError: name 'argument' is not defined

def numbers_to_months(argument):
   # switcher - dictionary with all months
   switcher = {
       1: one,
       2: two,
       3: three,
       4: four,
       5: five,
       6: six,
       7: seven,
       8: eight,
       9: nine,
       10: ten,
       11: eleven,
       12: twelve      # enum def twelve() -> str
       # 12: twelve(argument)

   }
   # get the function from switcher dictionary
   func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: ("Invalid month [1-12] : your input : {input}".format(input=argument)))

   # more information
   print(" - switcher.get : {info}  -  {arg}".format(info=switcher.get(argument), arg=argument))
   print(" - func : {info}  -  {arg}".format(info=func, arg=argument))

   # execute the function
   print(func())
   print()


numbers_to_months(13)

numbers_to_months(3)

numbers_to_months(12)

numbers_to_months(31)
```

---

#### Solution by Michail Highkhan , and thanks.

Every function one to twelve has to accept argument(s)/parameter(s)

```
  ...
    def twelve(argument):
        print(' --- in function :  twelve : {input}'.format(input=argument))
        ...


    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda arg : ("Invalid month [1-12] : your input : {input}".format(input=argument)))



...
print(func(78))
```

Original code/tutorial : https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html

Comment: Ok, the last tutorial you link is plain horrible...It starts with code that isn't Python but Java, and the code HAS NO ENUM, just a switch statement on functions. The youtube tutorial doesn't seem bad, but its about a "concept" of closure functions. Then you ask about specific difficulties with the switch code. I'm left not knowing what exactly you expect out of an answer. An explanation of the switch? An Enum  alternative? An Enum with switch? Because that's almost like writing an essay and the problem is you may not find the answer satisfactory anyway...

Comment: @bad_coder thanks for your quick reaction.
I just try to understand how it works, the tutorial uses closure functions. In a way I hoped that  I could use the idea.
[To avoid double coding]
Maybe it's a horrible tutorial (your opinion), but the idea works and yeah sounds good and great if you understand the functionality.

My apologize that my questions were not clear. I hope that I made it more clear. I have a long way to go to learn programming ... so thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a thing in python, that's called function object. You create one when you declare new function.

   ```
   def func(arg):
       print(arg)
       return arg
   ```

So now `func` - is object. You may store it somewhere, in a dict for example (just like you did) and use it later. And you can call it `func(1)` and get a result. Pycharm is smart enough to find where you did declare methods and show you info about it.

2. Your switcher has to return function object, that is to call later

   ```
   print(func()) # << here, see brackets after func
   ```

So default object also has to be function object. Lambda is just enother way to create it. Look here https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html

3. You can pass arguments to functions, but here it's not the point. Here function IS argument, that is taken from switcher by key an passed to `print`.

**UPD**
You can pass arguments to the function you've stored earlier when calling it. Let's try it with my earlier example:

```
d = {'func': func} # store function
result = d['func'](1) # get stored function and call it with argument
print(result)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: thanks for the link to lambdas and your quick response.
You are correct there is no need here.
But with  print(" - switcher.get : {info}  -  {arg}".format(info=switcher.get(argument), arg=argument))
   print(" - func : {info}  -  {arg}".format(info=func, arg=argument))

Comment: you see the functions, returns passing, but how to pass arguments/parameters to the functions over here. Which are linked in the switcher dictionary. That is one of my biggest issues ... 
Lets me say it ottherwise, if I look to the code of the switcher then I would say the code is pointing to variables one, two, three ... instead of functions.

Comment: so in your case you can prepare your functions to accept argument and pass it here: `print(func())`

Comment: @ Michail Highkhan Unfortunately this doesn't work 
` TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` 
 If I change the lambda code then ... 
` func = switcher.get(argument , lambda (arg): ("Invalid month [1-12] : your input : {input}".format(input=argument))) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax `

Comment: Look at sintax of lambda expressions - it desn't need brackets around argument you passed it. Like this: `lambda arg: print(arg)`